# how to get file with int-ftp:outbound-gateway and remove from server if exists?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

thanks for attention
i used `int-ftp:outbound-gateway` with `mget` command, i want to when retrieve file from server if file that retrieve from server exists in local directory then thrown bellow exception :

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Local file .\backup\a\in\a.in already exists
```

adapter code is:

```
<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayGET"
                              local-directory-expression="'./backup/' +#remoteDirectory"
                              session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                              request-channel="toGet"
                              reply-channel="toRemoveChannel"
                              command="mget"
                              command-options="-R"
                              expression="payload.remoteDirectory + '/' + payload.filename"/>
```

thans for help me.

Comment: You need to explain your use case more clearly,

Comment: thanks for reply @Gary, when run mget run commad on server , if files in server exists in local directory then thrown exception related to already exist file :( how to remove exists file in server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to ignore the error when a file already exists locally, please open a [new feature JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and we can add an option to the gateway.

In the meantime, one workaround I can think of is to `mget` them to a temporary directory and use a file outbound channel adapter to "move" the file to the final directory - it has an option to overwrite (replace) any existing file, while removing the temporary file.

Or, you can use LS to get the file names, remove them, and **then** do the mget.

Comment: thanks for @Gary, if use the `router` and rout the exists file to different channel for remove from server, what is your idea ? it's correctly?

Comment: No; if you want to ignore existing files, just force them to be removed first.