# Why int-ftp:outbound-gateway payload is not List<java.io.File>?

Tags: spring-integration, apache-commons-net

According to http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway the mget payload is a List of files

> mget retrieves multiple remote files based on a pattern and supports the following option:
>
> ...
>
> The message payload resulting from an mget operation is a ListFile> object - a List of File objects, each representing a retrieved file.

I have the following configuration

```
<int-ftp:outbound-gateway 
        session-factory="ftpSesionFactory"
        request-channel="request-channel"
        reply-channel="reply-channel" 
        auto-create-directory="true"
        local-directory="${local-directory}"        
        command="mget" 
        command-options="-stream" 
        expression="payload">
        <int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <int:retry-advice />
        </int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-ftp:outbound-gateway>
<int-file:splitter input-channel="reply-channel" output-channel="logger"/>
```

But the payload is a List<[FTPFile](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html)> and the splitter doesn't work. Is this a bug? How can I obtain the downloaded Listjava.io.File> in the payload (as the documentation says)?.

The workaround is using another component to read the file from the local directory, described at [how to get file with int-ftp:outbound-gateway and remove from server if exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766471/how-to-get-file-with-int-ftpoutbound-gateway-and-remove-from-server-if-exists).

I'm using spring-integration 4.2.5 and commons-net-2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you believe it's `List<FTPFile`?

[This test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ftp/outbound/FtpServerOutboundTests.java#L232) shows it's a `List<java.io.File>`.

The `ls` command returns either a list of `String` or `FTPFile`, depending on the `-1` option.

Finally, `-stream` is not supported on `mget`, only `get`.

Also, you don't want a file splitter there - that reads each file - you need a regular `<int:splitter/>` to split the `List<File>` into separate files; then the file splitter will read the file lines.